# odd bash script behaviour difference

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
m=1
for m in {1..115};
do
     n=$(ls|grep gif|awk NR==$((m)))
     echo "${n}"
     echo "convert "${n}" -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 $((m)).gif"
     convert "${n}" -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 $((m)).gif
done
```

so this is a simple bash script to list all the .gif extension files and then convert them ,it used to echo and convert names in the with the convert command uncommented but it got stuck at the first .gif name and continued on converting it till the loop ended (m is incremented normally) and i thought maybe that was because of the spaces in the gif name so i decided to debug it when i come home so when i reached home i powered the pc on again and i got a totally different situation which is if i comment the convert command `s line, the n variable is echoed as names which is what i expect but if i uncomment it n is echoed as a number that is incremented while looping.

thank you very much

Comment: `awk NR==$((m))` is quite a weird syntax. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This entire script is odd. Why are you looping over numbers instead of the actual files? `for gif in *.gif`?

Comment: print line by line in order to feed it to the convert

Comment: Is there a problem with your shift key?

Comment: @fedorqui That's an unquoted awk script with an arithmetic context expansion of `m`. Functionally identical to `NR==$m` in this case and a *wildly* inefficient way of getting the Nth matching file. (I imagine you may have known much of that so consider that address a rhetorical device.)

Comment: well the convert command decided to take all the gifs as a  single input to change them into one output

Comment: why would you say so @psmears

Comment: psmears comment was because you haven't used any proper capitalization on your sentences in the post or in your comments. Capitalization, punctuation and spacing make comprehension of what you've written easier for those of us who need to read it.

Comment: even if it is inefficient and i don't care for now but i still can't understand this behavior 's roots @Etan Reisner

Comment: What behavior? I had trouble understanding the exact complaint/problem in your wall of unformatted text. Can you clean up your post and clearly explain the problem you are asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is caused by parsing the output of `ls`repeatedly. Your output from `ls` isn't consistent between the loops. Each time through the loop you create a new `.gif` file which `ls` then includes in its output the next time through the loop. If the new files sort *before* the original files then you will get the new files as `n` and not your desired original files. The glob loop above does not have that problem as the glob is expanded once *before* any new files are created. The shell expands the glob *first* and then uses that literal list of filenames in the `for` loop.

That being said this is a very bizarre, unnecessarily limited (unless it stops at 115 files on purpose) and wildly inefficient way of operating on all the `.gif` files in the current directory.

You don't need `$((m))` to get the value of a variable. You can just use `$m`. `$((...))` is an arithmetic expression. You need that if you want to do math (which you aren't here).

You don't want to [parse the output from ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) it isn't safe or reliable.

Your `grep` there will match files that include `gif` in the name as well as the extension.

If you want to loop over all the `*.gif` files in the current directory the correct way to do that is to actually do just that.

```
for image in *.gif; do
    echo "Do something with $image"
done
```

In your case that would look like this (assuming you want numeric output files)

```
m=1
for image in *.gif; do
    m=$((m+1))
    echo "convert ${image} -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 $m.gif"
    convert "${image}" -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 "$m.gif"
done
```

Or, as kojiro correctly indicated, you can avoid the potentially inaccurate `echo` statement by using `set -x` to get the shell to output the commands it runs and use an array to avoid keeping your own counter

```
# The space here is important. It causes the glob expanded files to start at index 1 instead of 0 don't remove it.
images=([0]= *.gif)
set -x
for m in "${!images[@]}"; do
    convert "${images[m]}" -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 "$m.gif"
done
set +x
```

Comment: Didn`t do it unfortunately ,it treats image variable as a number @Etan Reisner

Comment: if do it manually it doesn't complain about anything.. @Etan Reisner

Comment: if issue "convert image_name.gif -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 output_name.gif "it behaves normally.@Etan Reisner

Comment: OP could also avoid manually maintaining the index altogether with an array, and guarantee parity between the `echo` and the actual command using `set -x`. `images=([0]= *.gif); set -x; for m in "${!images[@]}"; do convert "${images[m]}" -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 "$m.gif"; done; set +x`

Comment: what is even more confusing is that it used to work but it choked on the spaces in the input file name till it restarted then it wouldn't work anymore, but still can `convert` force the whole script to treat the variable as a number!!!@Etan Reisner

Comment: @kojiro Indeed but I was trying not to introduce too many things all at once (and originally I hadn't realized that the number was needed for the output file name).

Comment: @user3566929 Choking on spaces means you aren't quoting variable expansions. But that fact can't change unless your file names change. I have no idea what your `but still` sentence was supposed to mean. Do you actually want numerically named output files? Does using `"x$m.gif"` as the output filename argument in that snippet work better?

Comment: i am sorry if i am being confusing, what i meant was, i could've stopped at the fact that `convert` is glitchy but i am bewildered by the fact that when i comment it i get my expected names but if uncomment ,it forces the whole script to echo my variables as numbers @Etan Reisner

Comment: sorry my friend doesn't even print anything but it consumes my resources which could point out the `convert` could be stupid too.@kojiro

Comment: it choked even though i used quotes @Etan Reisner

Comment: i agree with you on the `ls` parsing issue and that's a very good resolution my friend but the problem now is to get `convert` to treat the variable as a name @Etan Reisner

Comment: if you please, post the `ls` parsing idea as an answer so i could mark it as true@Etan Reisner

Comment: `++ for m in '"${!images[@]}"';
++ convert '' -distort ScaleRotateTranslate 90 0.gif` that is the output and it doesn't terminate but `top` shows that nothing is going.@Etan Reisner

Comment: your code did it my friend, thanks a million.@Etan Reisner

Comment: i wanted to know how the `for image in *.gif` managed to get past the `ls` parsing issue; does it list once and cache, then reads from that cache?@Etan Reisner

Comment: @user3566929, `for image in *.gif` doesn't run `ls` at all, so it doesn't parse `ls` output at all, so how it avoids having an `ls` parsing issue should be rather obvious. :)